# rails 4 API gives 401 unathorized response after successful log in using angular2-token package

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I have a setup in which I have a rails 4 API having the gem devise_token_auth and hosted as a separate application so I have also rack-cors configured to handle cross origin requests. Using angular2-token on my front end Angular 2 applicaiton I have been able to successfully sign up and sign in as well as sign out users via my API.
The issue however, which I have encountered occurs only when the user is signed in and upon refreshing the browser I get this error in the rails API console as well as in the browser, checked in firefox as well as chrome.

```
Started GET "/api/v1/auth/validate_token" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-06 17:42:49 +0500
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::TokenValidationsController#validate_token as JSON
```

followed by

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."uid" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["uid", "abc@xyz.com"]]
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 76ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

My initial assumption during the configuration of this package in my Angular2 app was that it will implicitly include authentication headers in each request. However after repeatedly going through the gem's documentation I also added the headers myself when I initialize the token service in my app.component.ts file.

```
this._tokenService.init({
 apiPath: API_PATH,
  globalOptions: {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Accept':  'application/json',
      "access_token_name": localStorage.getItem('accessToken'),
      "client_name": localStorage.getItem('client'),
      "uid_name": localStorage.getItem('uid')
    }
  }
});
```

Even after that the response hasn't changed to the request and I was unable to receive these headers on the server end as well.

However after hours of inspection an idea finally came to me which was to inspect the headers m getting on the server and when I used ruby's request.header.inspect on my server end application I get the following output with the information required for validation of the token but it seems that the name of the keys of these header values are different form what the devise_token_auth expects to validate token (I went through the source of the devise_auth_token gem [here.](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/concerns/set_user_by_token.rb)

```
"HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "HTTP_EXPIRY"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "HTTP_UID"=>"abc@xyz.com", "HTTP_CLIENT_NAME"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "HTTP_TOKEN_TYPE"=>"Bearer"
```

What I believe is the user is not being set by the devise_token_auth gem based on the headers that are being passed.

After repeatedly going through the documentation of Angular2-token as well as devise_token_auth gem I am confused whether or not to manually add headers for authentication because I believe they are being passed already but with different keys.
I would just like to know if that is the case I am experiencing its been almost a full day and I cannot figure out a way to pin point the reason behind the 401 response.

Thanks a lot.

**EDITED:**

Moreover I am also getting nil when accessing current_user or any devise helper after successful sign in on server end.

Here are the rack-cors configuration for my api rails applicaiton as well.
**application.rb**

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '/cors',
      :headers => :any,
      :methods => [:post],
      :credentials => true,
      :max_age => 0
    resource '*',
      :headers => :any,
      :expose  => ['access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client'],
      :methods => [:get, :post, :options, :delete, :put]
  end
end
```

The headers I get upon inspecting are following:

1. HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN
2. HTTP_CLIENT
3. HTTP_EXPIRY
4. HTTP_TOKEN_TYPE
5. HTTP_UID

These are the headers sent even if I don't mention any headers while configuring the angular2-token package.

I am confused why it lets me login in the first place and later throw an error with a 401 code and response of

```
 {"success":false,"errors":["Invalid login credentials"]}
```

When I try and manually check token's validation using the following code

```
this._tokenService.validateToken().subscribe(
  res =>      console.log(res),
  error =>    console.log(error)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also pass `Expiry` and `Token-type` on requests for devise_token_auth to authenticate, something like this:

```
let headers = new Headers();

headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Uid', this.uid);
headers.append('Client', this.client);
headers.append('Access-Token', this.access_token);
headers.append('Expiry', this.expiry);
headers.append('Token-Type', 'Bearer');

this.http.post('http://my-api.com/', JSON.stringify(resource), {headers: header}).subscribe((res)=>{
    #Your Logic Here
});
```

This example is for generic HTTP requests, but you can apply that rule on your angular token plugin. ie.:

```
this._tokenService.init({
 apiPath: API_PATH,
  globalOptions: {
     headers: {
       'Content-Type':  'application/json',
       'Accept':  'application/json',
       "access_token_name": localStorage.getItem('accessToken'),
       "client_name": localStorage.getItem('client'),
       "uid_name": localStorage.getItem('uid'),
       "expiry_name": localStorage.getItem('expiry'),
       "token-type_name': 'Bearer'
    }
   }
 });
```

You have set custom headers name for `devise_token_auth`? First example works with default configuration, without `_name` in the end of the headers' names, you should try modifying if that is the case.

Comment: Thanks alot for the response! I will try that right a way!

Comment: actually I tried these changes earlier as well with no luck. Even if I pass no headers at all in the global options, upon inspecting the headers on the server end I am getting these values but with different keys as I have mentioned in my question. Does it have to anything with rack-ors configurations on my server end or anything else?
Moreover I am also getting nil when accessing current_user or any devise helper after successful sign in on server end

Comment: Have you exposed your headers at CORS config? Refer to this https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#cors

Comment: Yes sir I have. I have added my configs for rack-cors also in my question. I went on multiple online sources and after that I added the configurations I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: From what I could see, you should either rename default angular2-token headers to match the ones in you CORS configuration, or rename those and the fields that devise_token_auth uses like `DeviseTokenAuth.headers_names[:'access-token'] = "HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN"` on initializer

Comment: tried that as well but it didnt work. I am confused about why it lets me login and later throws an unauthorized error with the message "invalid login credentials"

Answer (score 1):

After spending a few days on this issue and going through multiple threads of related issues repeatedly posted on related topics I came across the [following](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/28) issue and I realized I have rails 4 and have used rails-api gem to generate my API.
After that I created a rails 5 API with **--api** option (without rails-api gem) and with **devise_token_auth** and **rack-cors** on my api end I was successful in sending authorized request using the **angular2-token** package. Along with that I was also able to send authorized http post requests with the authorization headers access-token, token-type, expiry, uid as mentioned in the devise_token_auth gem's documentation.

This might not be the exact solution or I may not have pinpointed the cause of the issue but this was what worked for me.